# Unable to get value from model

Tags: objective-c, ios

I receive a SIGABRT when I try to get a non-null variable. Code:

```
NSLog(@"%@", appDelegate.xmlData.magDictionary);
for (Magazine *ibb in appDelegate.xmlData.magDictionary) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [ibb title]);
}
```

Output:

```
   {
        1 = "<Magazine: 0x6c8fe10>";
        2 = "<Magazine: 0xf168d00>";
        3 = "<Magazine: 0xf169f50>";
        4 = "<Magazine: 0xf16b6d0>";
        5 = "<Magazine: 0xf170490>";
        6 = "<Magazine: 0xf1716c0>";
        7 = "<Magazine: 0xf172a80>";
        8 = "<Magazine: 0xf173f10>";
    }
```

and SIGABRT on NSLog(@"%@", [ibb title]);
The Magazine model: @synthesize title, key, teaser, tags, items, progressBar;

Comment: `@property` definition is more interesting than `@synthesize` in that case, `retain`, `assign`, `copy` ?

Comment: @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;

Comment: I guess `title` properties haven't been set properly. Have a look where you alloc/init your `Magazine` objects.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! "-(Magazine *) initWithMagazine:(Magazine *) originalMag { title = [originalMag title]; }" I don't have to     "title = [[NSString alloc] init];
 title = [originalMag title];" right?

Comment: I suggest : `title = [[originalMag title] copy];`, also define the property using `copy`. Also `title = [[NSString alloc] init]; title = [originalMag title];` is wrong. Using `initWithString:[originalMas title]` would have been better, without `title = [originalMag title];` after.

Comment: @Jon Suggest that you edit your question to include the code in your comments and delete the code comments. More complete code will facilitate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments, it appears that you do wrong in your `Magazine` initializer.
Using `retain` mode for the property doesn't really matter, but I would have used `copy` instead for string.

Anyway, the `title` string coming from `originalMag` isn't retained, or copied at all when assigned to the `title` ivar of your `Magazine`, thus I bet it is deallocated before you try to print any value, causing the crash.

Another point, doing :

```
title = [[NSString alloc] init];
title = [originalMag title];
```

generates a memory leak (and you still don't retain the original `title`).
Rewrite the initializer like so :

```
-(id)initWithMagazine:(Magazine *)originalMag {
    .....
    title = [[originalMag title] copy];
    // or title = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[originalMag title]];
    ....
}
```

and this should solve your app crash.